# Use a different naming convention for signed apks generated using the wizard on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, signing

I have an app with more than a few `buildFlavors` and three different `buildTypes`.

I generate the signed apks from `Build -> Generate Signed APK...`. (Unless there is no other go I'd like to continue using the wizard and not create a script, because i have a constantly increasing set of apps and do not want to modify the script every time.)

The generated apks are named in the following pattern:

> app-*flavorName-buildType*.apk

How can i change the naming pattern to something like this:

> app_*flavorName_buildType_versionCode*.apk

Changes I want to make:

1. Suffix file name with `versionCode`
2. Replace hyphens with underscores

I used to do it in `ant` using `task`, but not sure how to do it with `gradle`.

Trying to figure a solution to create the name straight away in the new pattern rather than trying to rename it once it is generated. Is that possible?

I tried looking under `Settings -> Gradle` but did not find anything. Any other place i should be looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not exactly what you are looking for.

You can use your build.gradle to set this attribute:

```
android {
    //...

    defaultConfig {
        //...
        project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "app_"+ defaultConfig.versionCode);
    }
}
```

Assigning the `archivesBaseName` you will obtain something like:

```
app_0.9.6-flavorName-buildType.apk
```

This attribute requires the gradle-plugin `1.3.1` or higher.

Otherwise you have to use a task to rename the apk after building.

Comment: That should suffice. Let me quickly try it out. Thanks!

Comment: oh but it wont replace the hyphens right? but still solves one of my problems of how to get the `versionCode`.

Comment: @AndroidMechanic Yes, as I described it is not exactly what you are looking for. I don't know how to replace the hyphens.

Comment: added `project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "app_"+ defaultConfig.versionCode);` under defaultConfig but it generated the apk with the same pattern as before. should it be put some other place and not in `defaultConfig`?

Comment: @AndroidMechanic Which version of gradle-plugin are you using? It requires 1.3.1 or higher

Comment: ah.. I'm on 1.3.0 ... let me check with a higher version ... `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'`

Comment: The com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1 fixed this problem (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system check the 1.3.1 changes)

Comment: Wow, I updated gradle tools to 1.5.0 and have 31 errors (mostly for missing translation).. let me fix them (dont want to disable lint) and I'll get back after checking the real issue. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Yay! it worked with `1.5.0`, But i just used a simpler syntax of the same thing you suggested `project.archivesBaseName = "app_" + defaultConfig.versionCode;`. Thanks a lot! +1

Comment: For the rename part i can just use one of the many awesome tools oht there which does batch rename. But, will still hold on from accepting this answer so that the question is not ignored (being accepted). Just in case someone knows how to do it from within gradle settings itself. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. But don't use project.archivesBaseName  instead of project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "AnotherName");
> Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been
> deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read
> http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html

Comment: oh okay... I also went ahead and edited your answer with that. :-( I'll revert it. Thanks for the correction.